# ASSEMBLY - example, MOV (two's complement and SXMD - sign extension mode)

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, mov

Here i am coming up with an quite easy example but I'd like to make it clear:

I have numbers (values):**0.75** and **-0.125**
I am turning them into **'two's complement'** (U2 ~ floating point) binary system on **6 bits**.

(The pattern is **I2Q4 (IkQn)** what means i have two bits (k-bits) of total part and four (n-bits) of fractional part - it looks like this   **_ _ . _ _ _ _**  .)
I turned these numbers (0.75 and -0.125) into binary (U2 - two's complement) system/form and they are respectively equal to:

**001100** (0.75) and **111110** (-0.125).

We assing symbols (name them) to the 6-bit words:
Let  **001100** (0.75) become **WA** and let **111110** (-0.125) become **WB** .
***Ok i'm coming to the meritum:***

Considering CPU's work on 6 bits word coded in two's compliement system and having 12-bits-accumulator and switched on SXM (sign extension mode) make these two orders:

*ORDER 1:* **MOV #WA,<<2,A**

*ORDER 2:* **MOV #WB,A**

(note that of course these two orders are done independently and they do not interact each other - I mean the doubts with A being the same in these two orders mentioned).

My question is:

1.How will it look like? ( I can do it but unfortunately may it be i do it correct without proper knowlege).

2.What does the '<<2' synthax mean?

3. Why is the '#' present in the synthax and why isnt it MOV WB,A (see question 4)?
4. Is it an addressing pattern (i mean absolute, direct, immediate etc.) that
   makes the synthax in order MOV #WB,A not MOV A,WB (may it the then it would have to be done in two steps?).

Please if you know answer on any o these questions please reply if it needs wider explaination (no 4) and you dont want spend your time please write a hint.

Sorry if the example spoils your knowledge by being super easy. All my respect to all the kings of asseblstion I claim. Thank you.

Comment: What processor and assembler is this?

Comment: Are you using a C55 DSP based chip?

Comment: This is a counting example but it is C55xx digital signal processor from Texas Instruments and this is in case of Code Composer Studio assemblation i think at 100% rate. I am very sorry for not submitting this.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS320#C5000_series) that C55x chips are 16bit DSPs.  Are you sure about the 6bit-word / 12bit-accumulator description you included in the question?  IDK that CPU, so I'll just say that 2's complement sign-extension copies the sign-bit from the top of the input to fill in the extra bits.  If you have a 6bit immediate value in an 8bit operand, sign extension will be looking at the top of the 8bit, not at the top of your 6bit bitfield.